# Android - Push Notifications

Tags: android

I am currently building a messaging application that allows users to send and receive messages on their Android mobile phones over an internet connection to each other. I have decided that I do not want to use polling because it means that a user may not receive another user's messages as instant as possible. I have my own server available for use.

I am currently tied between using Google's Cloud Messaging for Android platform in order to send the notifications from the server to the Android device. The other option is to keep a live TCP connection between my server and the Android device via a service, and send 'keep alive' messages every 5 minutes for example.

From your best opinion, what is the best way to do this - or is there a better way? I don't want to use third parties apart from Google to do this. There are similar answers available, but they don't address this specifically.

Alex

Comment: Looking for a chat App?Then GCM is not something you are looking for...,Its like broadcasting,Search on stackoverflow,you will find number of other related topic.

Comment: Ty, but there is nothing that addresses this specifically which is why I am asking.

Comment: [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873115/xmpp-openfire-push-notifications-android)

Answer (score 0):

> using Google's Cloud Messaging for Android platform in order to send the notifications from the server to the Android device.

This is not a realtime notification either; the notifications may be delayed longer than you experienced with polling. Also GCM is meant for broadcasting messages to a number of users, not for targeting a message to one specific user.

> The other option is to keep a live TCP connection between my server and the Android device via a service

I don't know how many users you are expecting, but this may not scale. You are limited in the number of TCP connections to one server.

No need to re-invent the wheel here, use an existing implementation such as XMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-test-android

It may be what you're looking for

Comment: *Would vote up if I could too*. I will go with XMPP.