# Push notification with openfire in Android

Tags: android, openfire

I'm building a chat application in android. I used both openfire as server and mysql and successfully implemented chat between two users. But I have following questions: 
1.I want to know is it possible to send push notification with this server. And if yes then how to achieve it? 
2. I'm planning to register new user through webservice ,so is it possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873115/xmpp-openfire-push-notifications-android